# Laravel 5.2 + Angular JS UI Routing not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am developing a web application with Angular as frond end and Laravel 5.2 as back end.

this is my laravel code.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('Aemployees',['uses'=>'AdminController@AngEmployeeList']);
```

AdminController.php

```
public function AngEmployeeList(){
    return View::make('admin.angular.anguemployees');
}
```

View( anguemployees.blade.php)

```
 @extends('admin.template')

 @section('title', 'Angular Employees')

 @section('content')
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="Employees">
<section class="content-header">
<h1>Data Tables</h1>
<span><a href="{{URL::to(route('new_emp'))}}">Add new</a></span>
</section>
<div class="box">
<div class="box-body">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Updated At</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td ng-bind="employee.emp_name"></td>
        <td ng-bind="employee.emp_mobile"></td>
        <td ng-bind="employee.emp_email"></td>
        <td ng-bind="employee.updated_at"></td>
        <td>
          <span><a class="editThis" ng-click="edit(employee.pk_emp_id)"></a></span>
          <span><a class="dltThis" ng-click="deleteItem(employee.pk_emp_id)"></a></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>          
    </table>
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div><!-- /.box -->
</div><!-- /.col -->
@endsection
```

Angularscripts.js

```
var EmployeeApp = angular.module('EmployeeApp',['ui.router']);

EmployeeApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouteProvider){

  $stateProvider.state('employees',{templateUrl : '/Aemployees'});
});


EmployeeApp.controller('Employees',function($scope,$http){
$http.get(BASEURL+'/getemployees')
.success(function(response){
    $scope.employees = response;
});

$scope.deleteItem = function (item_id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete ?") == true){
        $http.post(BASEURL+'/deletemployees',{pk_id:item_id})
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.employees = response;
        });
    }
}
});
```

The Output is not working perfectly and getting an error in console.

[image]

How can I fix this issue ?

Is the any error in my code ?

Comment: your templates shouldn't include any scripts ...just the content that will go into `<ui-view>`. You don't even need backend to serve those html templates although you can. Need to inderstnd that you only load one page...and everything else gets manipulated in that one page by router and directives

Comment: so you are saying that I need to remove the laravel template engine and use the angular UI routing template feature right ?

Comment: basically yes. Think of laravel as nothing but a data api. You could have it send templates but those can just as easily be `.html` files stored anywhere